# ios9 TouchID detection if fingerprint was added or removed

Tags: ios, objective-c, hash, ios9, touch-id

I integrated touch id in my app.I want to use the touch id as a second secure authentication. I want to detect if new fingerprints were added or removed. Could you help me with programmatically usage?

Comment: Not possible, the touch ID information is very locked down.

Comment: Possible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25669172/ios8-touchid-detection-if-fingerprint-was-added.

Answer (score 1):

There is no information available to an app that indicates when a fingerprint was added to or removed from the device.

**Update**

This is now possible in iOS9. The property evaluatedPolicyDomainState has been added to LAContext.  - See https://stackoverflow.com/a/38399751/1066762

Comment: If the fingerprint database is modified (fingers were added or removed), the data returned any item in iOS 9 ?  Can I detect if a new fingerprint was added to my device since the last time that I used? Because  very easy to get the device passcode.I want to use the fingerprint as a way of secure authentication.

Comment: TouchID is no more secure than the passcode, since if you have the device passcode then you can enroll a new fingerprint. There is no information available that notifies you of changes to the TouchID data

Comment: this answers your question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38399751/1066762

Comment: Yes, the APIs have been updated since I answered. I have added a link to that answer.  Thanks